# Open and read an .XML using only OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: python, opencv

I was using opencv-3.2.0 but I was forced to go back to 3.1.0. Now in 3.2.0 I was reading an XML file that contained the calibration parameters from my cameras. I have done those from a C++ tool I created using OpenCV as well. What I did then was:

```
f= cv2.FileStorage(calibration_file,cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
K = f.getNode("K").mat()
D = f.getNode("D").mat()
```

I found this by trial and error as there is (or I couldn't find) a reliable commplete Python OpenCV documentation. 3.1.0 opencv fileStorages do not appear to have getNode() method, so how can I open and read these files?

Due to some internet policies in my company I am not able to download any other Python package, so I'm interested in a solution using OpenCV-3.1.0 only. Changing back to 3.2.0 is not an option, and neither it is using C++.

Comment: As far as I remember, before it could only load one variable... and it was done like : `K=np.asarray(cv.Load(filename))` this was for like 2.4 or 3.0 I do not remember now. I think you may need to do cv2.cv now. In c++ version it was possible to load different variables from the same file

Comment: I ended up coding a very simple parser for my data and using the xml built in python library, but I'm still curious about how to do this...